# How to avoid to jump on the top when clicking on anchor with ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I created a CSS/HTML carousel with 4 slides and, when clicking on the button on the bottom (a href), it will display the selected slide. The problem is that every time I click a link, i can see the selected slide as I want, but the page jumps on the top. I know that the problem is because I used an ID, but I don't know how to avoid my page jumping. I tried adding this script:

```
$('a.someclass').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

this is the html:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slides">
        <div id="slide-1"></div>
        <div id="slide-2"></div>
        <div id="slide-3"></div>
        <div id="slide-4"></div>
    </div>
    <a href="#slide-1" class="slide-button">Slide 1</a>
    <a href="#slide-2" class="slide-button">Slide 2</a>
    <a href="#slide-3" class="slide-button">Slide 3</a>
    <a href="#slide-4" class="slide-button">Slide 4</a>
</div>
```

but it doesn't work.
How can I do? Thanks

Comment: Replace `somelcass` with `slide-button`

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong. Use a.slide-button instead of a.someclass

$() needs to be a valid jQuery DOM selector

```js
$('a.slide-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.slides {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
    <div class="slides">
        <div id="slide-1"></div>
        <div id="slide-2"></div>
        <div id="slide-3"></div>
        <div id="slide-4"></div>
    </div>
    <a href="#slide-1" class="slide-button">Slide 1</a>
    <a href="#slide-2" class="slide-button">Slide 2</a>
    <a href="#slide-3" class="slide-button">Slide 3</a>
    <a href="#slide-4" class="slide-button">Slide 4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried modifying the code but I still have the same problem, it still jumping in the top page

Comment: @quri_design have you included jQuery? Try running my code above, it's a working example.

Comment: Yes I've added it but it didn't work. I tried to insert it both in head and in body